# Suggestions for hosted file sharing services

Tags: hosting, ftp, web-hosting, file-sharing, remote

Before I pose my question, I will give some insight as per my scenario:

- I work for a small business (cost is an important factor)
- Our bandwidth is limited and would not support an in-house FTP server

We need to share files (mostly pdf, inDesign, Illustrator documents) to our clients, and as we expand, we are finding that our current locally-hosted FTP solution is too slow and is becoming a detriment to our sales team. What we need is a **remotely hosted** solution to share files with our clients, specifically with the following features:

- Greater than 100gb of secure storage
- The Ability to distribute unique log in credentials to clients, granting access to a personalized directory or folder, while limiting access to other files on the server.
- A relatively simple web-based UI for clients with limited computer knowledge

We have considered a dedicated remote server, and web-based services (box.net, yousendit.com, onehub.com, filesanywhere.com) but I am unsure as per the direction we should be taking - have I left another solution out?

What would *you* suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

File sharing services such as Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/features) or any of those you mentioned will work well as an alternative to FTP and meet all of the needs you described. As an 'part-time' IT person myself, this is what I would recommend as the most convenient, usable, cost-effective, and secure solution.

Answer (score 0):

Several of my clients have had great success using [Jungle Disk](http://www.jungledisk.com/) business class.  It's inexpensive, and the business version has flexible permissions and access controls, as well as encryption and backup solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try Humyo. UK based storage solutions provider, also has multiple content servers physically located.

www.humyo.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, found Humyo via Wikipedia earlier today and it seems to work great using the free version. My only issue with it is that when I share files to my 'test' email addresses, they seem to get caught in my spam filter.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking for a similar solution, I haven't decided yet but [Transfers](http://onehub.com/products/transfers) from OneHub looks promising as well.